# Efficient domain filtering using regex in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, performance

I'm building a rack server app that has to filter domains that can access the data.
This is currently how i do that and it works fine:

```
   authorized_domains = /domain1.com|domain2.com|domain3.com/
   return [417, {"Content-Type" => "text/html"}, ["Expectation Failed"]] unless env['HTTP_REFERER'].match(authorized_domains)
```

The problem is that i would get probably half a million request a day
or even more, and on top of that i would have about 1000-3000 domains on the list.

Is this the most efficient filtering there is? doing a regex on the list of domains?

Comment: Authorization on HTTP_REFERER isn't all that great since it's easy to fake.

Comment: @JonasElfström i know but i don't care since i'm sending fonts. what kind of end user would fake his HTTP_REFERER to see a face-font style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the domains as a [`Set`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/index.html) in a class constant so that it doesn't get instantiated on each request. Then get the domain.tld from the HTTP_REFERER and do a look-up in the set.

Something like

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rack'
require 'set'
require 'URI'

class FontServer
  DOMAINS = %w[domain1.com domain2.com domain3.com].to_set
  def call(env)
    uri = URI.parse(env['HTTP_REFERER'])
    domain_tld = uri.host.split('.')[-2..-1].join('.')
    return [417, {"Content-Type" => "text/html"}, ["Expectation Failed"]] unless DOMAINS.include? domain
  end
end
```

@pguardiario argued that the above is slower than his regex solution. To benchmark is to know.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rack'
require 'set'
require 'URI'
require 'benchmark'

domains=[]
3000.times {|i| domains<<"domain#{i}.com"}
DOMAINS = domains.to_set
re = Regexp.new('^https?:\/\/(' + domains.join('|') + ')')
env = {'HTTP_REFERER' => 'http://domain4711.com/'}

Benchmark.bm do |benchmark|
puts "pguardiario regex"
benchmark.report do
    100000.times do
      env['HTTP_REFERER'] =~ re
    end
  end
  # Parsing the URL with the URI gem and getting domain.tld
  # About three times faster than the regex solution
  puts "jonelf original"
  benchmark.report do
    100000.times do
      uri = URI.parse(env['HTTP_REFERER'])
      domain_tld = uri.host.split('.')[-2..-1].join('.')
      DOMAINS.include? domain_tld
    end
  end
  # Set::include? is really fast. If we only got a
  # fast way to get the domain it would rock.
  puts "Only the set look-up"
  benchmark.report do
    domain_tld="domain4711.com"
    100000.times do
      DOMAINS.include? domain_tld
    end
  end
  # Gets the full host instead of just domain.tld
  # so that it does the same as pguardiario did
  # About 3.8 times faster than the regex on my machine.
  puts "A tweaked solution"
  benchmark.report do
    100000.times do
      DOMAINS.include? URI.parse(env['HTTP_REFERER']).host
    end
  end
end
```

```
      user     system      total        real
pguardiario regex
  8.437000   0.000000   8.437000 (  8.538086)
jonelf original
  2.719000   0.000000   2.719000 (  2.734375)
Only the set look-up
  0.047000   0.000000   0.047000 (  0.040039)
A tweaked solution
  2.203000   0.000000   2.203000 (  2.222656)
```

Comment: You are much appreciated Jonas. The ruby syntax is new to me so i will try to call this class from my existing code, thank you

Comment: and WOW that URI library is awesome!

Comment: The extra overhead will actually make this solution less efficient than regex in most cases

Comment: Hmm, I said in most cases. You benchmarked one specific case, and it was one that made you look good.

Comment: You can rest assure that I didn't do that on purpose and are very much welcome to provide a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

I think because of the amount of domains and hits per day the best way would be to store them in a table, add an index and then query it whenever needed. You can even keep the table in memory (depeding on the DBMS) so that the queries run faster.

Comment: But then i'm dealing with concurrent query connections limits

Comment: Can you leave the connection open and use the same connection for each request?

Comment: No, this will make my app act as a Comet server. I don't want that

Comment: :( Go for a set then: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/classes/Set.html

Comment: Is it possible to save the domain names in a file and use that for the set?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. I just know the Set is quite fast as it hashes the data. Even if it is possible to keep them in a file then you'll have to open and close the file each time. If you keep the file open then you'll have to close it anyway to make changes on it. Maybe keeping them in a separate Ruby class would do the trick (keeping them away from the code and making them more or less editable)

Answer (score 0):

It's faster to add the ^https?:// because the regex doesn't have to look everywhere in the string, only in the beginning:

```
domains = ['domain1.com', 'domain2.com', 'domain3.com'] * 1000
env = {'HTTP_REFERER' => 'http://domain4.com/'}
re = Regexp.new('^https?:\/\/(' + domains.join('|') + ')')

500000.times do
    env['HTTP_REFERER'] =~ re
end
```

**Edit**

Well there are benchmarks and there are benchmarks but @Jonas Elfstrom semms to take the cake :) Let's try to show why you shouldn't take all benchmarks seriously:

```
domains=[]
3000.times {|i| domains<<"domain#{i}.com"}
# let's assume the referrer is in the top 10 of whitelisted referrers.
# I'm not trying to introduce bias, I actually think that's reasonable.
env = {'HTTP_REFERER' => 'http://domain10.com/'}

Benchmark.bm do |benchmark|
  puts "pguardiario regex"
  benchmark.report do
    re = Regexp.new('^https?:\/\/(' + domains.join('|') + ')')
    100000.times do
      env['HTTP_REFERER'] =~ re
    end
  end

  puts "Only the set look-up"
  benchmark.report do
    DOMAINS = domains.to_set
    domain_tld = "domain4711.com" # huh?
    # Um, excuse me? You think you can get away with hardcoding that? lol :)

    100000.times do
      # how about if we parse on the fly like we would have to do in real life.
      domain_tld = URI.parse(env['HTTP_REFERER']).host
      DOMAINS.include? domain_tld
    end
  end
end
```

---

> ```
>    user     system      total        real
> ```

pguardiario regex

> 0.203000   0.000000   0.203000 (  0.200012)

Only the set look-up

> 2.371000   0.000000   2.371000 (  2.386136)
>
> Result: Sorry @Jonas, not even close.

Comment: hmm this is interesting but the syntax is a little strange to me. what does env['HTTP_REFERER'] =~ re do?

Comment: It's actually the same thing as match.

Comment: you would just change your regex to: /^https?:\/\/(domain1.com|domain2.com|domain3.com)/

Comment: You can simplify the regex by using interpolation and a different literal form that makes escaping the slashes unnecessary: `re = %r[^https?://(#{domains.join('|')})]`.